# Beveled edges rendering like they're cut into

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, bevel, motion-capture

I made a very simple animation, and with camera movement, the beveled edges appear as if they are cut into. How can I fix this?

I am rendering with blender render.

[image]

Comment: Its will be better to have your .blend file.

Comment: blender file here: https://ufile.io/h7cka

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add motion blur, but that didn't help!

Comment: the file you linked is not available for my region, do you use google drive, instead?

Comment: who told you to add motion blur?

Comment: No one, I was just trying things. One second, let me add to google drive

Comment: when I click on render first it renders small height-ed rectangular and when it finishes rendering it becomes normal rectangle as expected, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: are you using some interleaved codec?

Comment: @yash, same happens for me! idk why.

Comment: @samir - I don't even know what that means. lol. I am very new to blender!

Comment: I am rendering from the .blend by clicking animation into an .avi file

Comment: Solved it! I needed to uncheck "fields" under Post Processing. 

What that does, I don't know, but unchecking it fixed it! 

Thank you!

Comment: @user68946 as you got the answer, you should post by clicking "Answer your question" comments are not noticeable so you should answer your question yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! just added!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I needed to uncheck "fields" under Post Processing. What that does, I don't know, but unchecking it fixed it! Thank you!

Comment: It is called interlacing. Back in the 20th century (yes, blender is that old). TV motion's flicker was solved by refreshing the screen twice for every frame with a horizontal interlaced beam. The first pass would refresh the even field, the second pass the odd ones. Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlaced_video